# Docker: Ruby version upgrade from 2.2.0 to 2.4.0

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.4

I am using Ruby version `2.2.0` in my Rails Application and Rails version is `4.2.0`.
Currently, Project is built through docker, so I am thinking of to upgrade the ruby version with `2.4.0` version.

I believe I need to change the docker image to upgrade the ruby version.

I already check a few of the articles but didn't get enough information.

**Docker file**

```
FROM ruby:2.2.0

RUN apt update && \
  apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
  git \
  curl \
  gnupg2 \
  libpq-dev \
  libmysqlclient-dev \
  nodejs \
  graphviz \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Once ruby version upgraded then I will upgrade the rails version.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the last ruby version is 2.6.4, not 2.4.0. I'm not sure if I'm missing something...

Comment: `FROM ruby:latest`?

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: @Mr. the question implies that I need to upgrade the ruby version

Comment: @Stefano yes you're correct, I just want to upgrade the ruby version from 2.2.0 to 2.4.0

Comment: @LinPy I will try with `FROM ruby:latest`

Comment: this will bring you to version 2.6.4, if you want to go with v. 2.4 you can try with `FROM ruby:2.4` (but it'll bring you v. 2.4.7)

Answer (score 1):

You can always build your own Docker image as such:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential wget

RUN wget --no-check-certificate -O ruby-install.tar.gz https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/archive/master.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzvf ruby-install.tar.gz
RUN cd ruby-install-master && make install
RUN cd /
RUN rm -rf ruby-install-master && rm -rf ruby-install.tar.gz

RUN ruby-install --latest
RUN ruby-install -i /usr/local/ ruby 2.4.0 -- --disable-install-doc

RUN gem update --system --no-document
RUN gem install bundler --force
```

Comment: we can do this for the existing project, right? I asked this because I am new docker.

Comment: @RohitLingayat It depends what you mean, you could incorporate some or all of the above in to an existing Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

depends on how one manages ruby application and ruby version. here are few things i would offer  to check:

1. update `Gemfile` if [`bundler`](https://bundler.io/v1.12/gemfile_ruby.html) is used

   ```sh
   $ cat Gemfile | head -n 1
   ruby '2.4.0'
   ```
2. update `.ruby-version` if [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version) or [`rvm`][3] is used

   ```sh
   $ cat .ruby-version
   2.4.0
   ```
3. update `Dockerfile` if docker is used

   ```sh
   $ cat Dockerfile | grep FROM
   FROM ruby:2.4.0
   ```